# Is it possible in PHP to:

Tags: php, cookies

Steal a specific cookie without them being redirected from the site you want to steal the cookie from

Example: Jim opens a link from skype and bob wants to steal a cookie from target.com

I found this script on google I understand what most of it does is there a way for it to do what I want in my example?

```
<?php
    $cookie = $_COOKIE["name"];
    $steal = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    fwrite($steal, $cookie ."\n"); //<---- Must be $cookie instead of $name
    fclose($steal);
?>
```

Comment: If it were that easy nobody would use cookies! You should ask this questions in a community who's website has a black background... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open the link form your site(parent window) in a new tab/window(child window). Get the cookie of the external site (child window). Pass the cookie to the parent window.

***Note:*** You can call a parent window function form child window. That the trick.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible. Only if Bob has an iframe (or script from his site) on Jims site or vice versa or YOU have a script on Jim's and Bob's site this could be done (it's what ad companies do)

[good and simple explanation of the matter](http://anantgarg.com/2012/02/18/busting-the-cookies-and-privacy-myth/)